# WCF DateTime Parameters

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that requires some DateTime parameters to be passed in.
The service will be used globally and be consumed by different clients (.NET, PHP etc).
What is the best format to get the datetime parameters in?
I was thinking of making them string parameters, and then advising the users of the format needed.

Maybe something like "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"

Then in the service I could do something like this;

```
DateTime usedatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(PassedDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I did try this, it worked fine on my local pc, but failed on the deployment server..."String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I guess my question is; What is the best way to handle date parameters in WCF?
I really hope that makes sense...

Comment: Your approach seems fine - and the YYYY-MM-DD format should be fine, too (it's the ISO-8601 format). Does it fail on your server when you try to start your service, or when you try to call into it??

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for the reply. It fails on the call. It fails on the line above, with the "invalid string" error. One thing I didn't mention before is that the server is a shared hosted environment. I am guessing that it must be something with the regional configuration on the server?? Im just not sure why it would see the string differently...This sort of thing is actually what I am trying to avoid :)

Comment: the exact error is "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Sorry, found the cause of the error, was a point in code that I had not converted correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem with the string PassedDate, what is in that variable?

Comment: Sorry, found the cause of the error, was a point in code that I had not converted correctly...

Comment: So back to my overriding question. Is using string type for the datetime parameters the accepted/preferred way to handle passing datetime parameters?

Comment: It depends, but as a string with a documented format, is a robust way to send a date between systems with various technologies and configurations.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz. I have decided to go with the string parameters and all seems fine. Thanks for the comments.